# NetworkManager not storing passwords

Tags: wifi, networkmanager

Today I noticed that NetworkManager is not storing passwords for WPA2 networks. I enter the password on connecting, but when I go to the *Network Connections* dialog the password field is blank and I get on the terminal:

```
** (nm-connection-editor:23985): WARNING **: Invalid setting Wi-Fi Security: Invalid Wi-Fi security
```

Even as root this happens. In fact, [network information is supposed to be in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22174/where-does-network-manager-store-wpa-keys-when-available-to-all-users-is-ticke) but this directory is empty.

For now I'm using wicd, even though it doesn't see much updating anymore. Any ideas?

I'm running Fedora 18 and the NetworkManager-related packages I have are:

```
NetworkManager-vpnc-0.9.3.997-3.fc18.x86_64
NetworkManager-glib-0.9.8.1-3.git20130514.fc18.x86_64
NetworkManager-openvpn-0.9.3.997-3.fc18.x86_64
NetworkManager-0.9.8.1-3.git20130514.fc18.x86_64
NetworkManager-pptp-0.9.3.997-3.fc18.x86_64
NetworkManager-openconnect-0.9.7.0-1.git20120918.fc18.x86_64
```

Comment: Is it an issue with SELinux? http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=288322

Comment: I disabled SELinux already, didn't help.

Comment: Did you look through the open issues? https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/bugs/NetworkManager

Comment: You might want to try a newer version of NM from here: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/search/NetworkManager?_csrf_token=d5656cc8817ab56457ab1453c988db62c6d3e971, as a last ditch effort if you can't resolve it any other way.

Comment: I will try it when I get home, then I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that reinstalling NetworkManager has worked.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `gnome-keyring` [is installed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1045730).

Answer (score 0):

Try forgetting your network and connecting back to it.